# Highchart - Data defined in a HTML table data to be passed in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Im new to Highcharts and trying to get the data defined in HTML table, but I'm not sure how to and what data to pass the JS file.

Like for example in this chart :
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

```
 series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

}, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

}, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

}, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

}]
```

});

The data to be sent to JS file is a list of dictionary but for 
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed 
this chart what should be series data or list I'm supposed to pass.

And is it possiblt to add new columns to table just for table not graph.

Comment: Unless you're hacking another website, this is the wrong way to go. Point being you should use the same data you used to create the `<table>`, not reverse engineer the data back into structural form. What you want is possible but so far you haven't made any attempt. What are you expecting?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu no im not hacking !   Ok my question is 
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }

this is where my data has to go ?  what are the variables here to pass my data

Comment: I suggest to read [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data) - you can define your own `start/end`+`row/column`, or `complete` callback to define which series shouldn't show up on a chart. More details regarding loading data into Highcharts can be found in the [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module).